# Jetpack Compose does not update my list with RxAndroid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to update a LazyColumn items using a subscriber to a RxAndroid Flowable. The state variable I'm using for the image list is called simply "list"

This is my LazyColumn code:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
) {
    items(list) { image ->
        Text(text = image.title ?: "Title")
    }
}
```

If for example, I run this test coroutine, the list is updated and shows the correct amount of test images:

```
GlobalContext.run {
            val testList = SnapshotStateList<Image>()
            for (i in 1..100) {
                testList.add(Image(i, null, null, null, null))
            }
            list = testList
        }
```

But if I try the same method using my subscription to a Flowable, it updates the variable value but the recomposition is not triggered. This is my code:

```
val observer = remember {
    disposable.add(
        viewModel.imagesObservable().subscribe(
            { images ->
                val snapList = SnapshotStateList<Image>()
                images.forEach {
                    snapList.add(Image(it.id, it.albumId, it.title, it.url, it.thumbnailUrl))
                }
                list = snapList
            },
            { Log.d("dasal", "Error: Can't load images") }
        )
    )
}
```

How do I handle a Flowable with a Composable?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was using this declaration

```
var list = remember { mutableStateListOf<Image>() }
```

I changed it to this one instead

```
val list = remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Image>()) }
```

Now I can use the `list.value` property to update/read the current value.